# How do I overrride fieldset.html template so that I can pass more arguments

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I am overriding the admin fieldset.html template?
I need to access the model.
I have a table called domain and I need to query the database (Domain.objects.all) get a list of all the domains and pass it to the template. 
How/where would I do it especially with respect to admin interface.
Thanks

Comment: It is simple to write your own admin view.

Comment: where do i put the new view. I don't see any documentation for overriding views

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for overriding the view:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods

Answer (score 0):

I find making a template tag usually works in this situation. In the template you are writing, you can usually make a tag, call it something like 'get_domains' that functions like this:

```
{% load mylibrary %}

{% get_domains as domains %}

{% for domain in domains.all %}
   {{ domain.name }}
{% endfor %}
```